# C#: When retrieve data from clipboard then getting NULL always

Tags: c#, clipboard

I have store the instance of my class in clipboard and when retrieve the same from clipboard then getting null always. i marked my class `[Serializable]` but still no luck. i am not being able to find out where i made the mistake. Here is my code. please have a look and tell me where i made the mistake and what to change in code as a result i should be able to retrieve the object i stored in clipboard. Thanks

```
//Save object to clipboard
private void BtnSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NodeCollection ndCollection = new NodeCollection();
    TunerDetails tds = null;
    selectednode = tvCsmTuner.SelectedNode;
    if (selectednode == null) return;

    if (selectednode != null)
    {
        ndCollection.Name = selectednode.Text;
        ndCollection.Text = selectednode.Text;
        ndCollection.Tag = selectednode.Tag;

        foreach (TreeNode node in selectednode.Nodes)
        {
            ndCollection.Nodes.Add(new NodeCollection { Name = node.Text, Text = node.Text, Tag = node.Tag });
        }

        DataObject data = new DataObject();
        data.SetData(ndCollection);
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);

    }

    RemoveNode();

}


//Read object back from clipboard
private void BtnGet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataObject retrievedData = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (retrievedData.GetDataPresent(typeof(NodeCollection)))
        {
            NodeCollection ndCollection1 = retrievedData.GetData(typeof(NodeCollection)) as NodeCollection;
            if (ndCollection1 != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ndCollection1.Name);
            }
        }
}


[Serializable]
public class NodeCollection 
{
    public NodeCollection() {
        Nodes = new List<NodeCollection>();
    }
    
    #region PROPERTIES
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Tag { get; set; }
    public List<NodeCollection> Nodes { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

In same application when i try to same object in clipboard this way then it worked. below code worked. so now i more confused that customer data getting store and retrieve in clipboard but my nodecollection class is not getting retrieve from clipboard.

```
DataObject mydata = new DataObject();
Customer c = new Customer("Customer as Customer object");
c.Nodes.Add(new Customer { Name = "Hello" });
mydata.SetData(c);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(mydata);

DataObject MyretrievedData = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (MyretrievedData.GetDataPresent(typeof(Customer)))
{
    Customer customer =
        MyretrievedData.GetData(typeof(Customer)) as Customer;
    if (customer != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(customer.Name);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer() { }
    private string nameValue = string.Empty;
    public Customer(String name)
    {
        nameValue = name;
        Nodes = new List<Customer>();
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return nameValue; }
        set { nameValue = value; }
    }

    public List<Customer> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because of this `RemoveNode();` which as it says removes the node from the collection. Comment it and try.

Comment: yes i commented it but still no luck

Comment: I see. Make sure what assigned to the `selectednode.Tag` property is also a serializable object. Also you don't need this `if (selectednode != null)` because the very previous line does that check already.